# NPM install error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am trying to install my npm dependencies on Ubuntu 14.04.3 (Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu) from package.json file. I don't know if it is important, but Ubuntu is a virtual machine. I install dependencies in /tmp directory so it isn't any shared folder or samba resource.

Node.js version: 0.12.7.

Npm version: 3.3.9.

Package.json:

```
{
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-loader": "5.3.*",
        "bootstrap": "3.3.*",
        "css-loader": "0.19.*",
        "del": "2.0.*",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "0.8.*",
        "file-loader": "0.8.*",
        "gulp": "3.9.*",
        "gulp-eslint": "1.0.*",
        "gulp-util": "3.0.*",
        "html-loader": "0.3.*",
        "karma": "0.13.*",
        "karma-chai-plugins": "0.6.*",
        "karma-mocha": "0.2.*",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "0.2.*",
        "karma-webpack": "1.7.*",
        "mocha": "2.3.*",
        "phantomjs": "1.9.*",
        "style-loader": "0.12.*",
        "url-loader": "0.5.*",
        "webpack": "1.12.*",
        "yargs": "3.27.*"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">= 0.12.0"
    }
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "4.13.*"
    }
}
```

I use --no-bin-links install flag (I need to copy node_modules directory to another NTFS based location).

When i am installing dependencies i have following error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at emit (events.js:107:17)
    at null.<anonymous>(/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js:14:10)
    at emit (events.js:107:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js:14:10)
    at emit (events.js:107:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js:14:10)
    at emit (events.js:107:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js:14:10)
    at emit (events.js:107:17)
at TrackerGroup.finish (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js:60:8)
```

Does anybody have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Another instance of [npm/npm#9224](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9224) I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You most probabbly experienced NPM Issues [#9224](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9224) or [#9239](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9239).

To work around the issues, you can install the packages into `/tmp` without the `--no-bin-links` flag and make sure that you replace the symlinks with files/dirs afterwards. You can use `rsync -L` to copy the files to NTFS with symlinks transformed into referent files and dirs.